# Ionic + ngCordova + background geolocation + DeviceReady issue

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to get the background geolocation plugin to work in my app; however, the page only sometimes loads on my device when I use the `deviceready` function. From my googling, it seems that I should be using `$ionicPlatform.ready` instead, but `$cordovaBackgroundGeolocation` is undefined when I try to do that. Similarly, the device is always undefined when I try to do anything with it.

I also tried manually bootstrapping angular, that didn't work; and I tried simply running the function without putting it inside `deviceready` or `$ionicPlatform.ready` or anything; that didn't work either.

The code in question:

Controller:

```
// Define the angular module
angular.module('testApp.controllers', ['ionic', 'ngCordova.plugins.geolocation', 'ngCordova.plugins.backgroundGeolocation'])

.controller('MapCtrl', ['$scope', '$ionicPopup', '$cordovaGeolocation', '$cordovaBackgroundGeolocation', '$timeout', '$http', '$ionicPlatform', 
               function ($scope, $ionicPopup, $cordovaGeolocation, $cordovaBackgroundGeolocation, $timeout, $http, $ionicPlatform) {
    $scope.loaded = false;

    var posOptions = { timeout: 5000, enableHighAccuracy: true, maximumAge: 5000 };
    $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(posOptions)
        .then(function (location) {
            $scope.currentLat = location.coords.latitude;
            $scope.currentLong = location.coords.longitude;
            $scope.loaded = true;
        });

    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        var bgGeo = $cordovaBackgroundGeolocation;

        // BackgroundGeoLocation is highly configurable.
        bgGeo.configure({
            url: 'http://www.my_api_url_here/',
            params: {
                deviceId: "testApp",
                "location": {
                    "latitude": "38.896339999999995",
                    "longitude": "-77.08521460000001"
                }
            },
            desiredAccuracy: 10,
            stationaryRadius: 20,
            distanceFilter: 30,
            notificationTitle: 'TestTitle', // <-- android only, customize the title of the notification
            notificationText: 'TestText', // <-- android only, customize the text of the notification
            activityType: 'OtherNavigation',
            debug: true, // <-- enable this hear sounds for background-geolocation life-cycle.
            stopOnTerminate: false // <-- enable this to clear background location settings when the app terminates
        });

        bgGeo.start();
    });
}])
```

Directive:

```
.directive('bgeo', ['$cordovaGeolocation', '$cordovaBackgroundGeolocation', '$http', 
           function ($cordovaGeolocation, $cordovaBackgroundGeolocation, $http) {
    return {
        scope: {
           lat: '=',
           lng: '='
       },
        link: function (scope) {
            console.log("directive: ", scope.lat, scope.lng);
                myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(scope.lat, scope.lng);
                mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 16,
                    center: myLatLng
                };
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatLng,
                    map: map,
                    draggable: false,
                    icon: 'small-orange-pin.png'
                });
        }
    }
}])
```

Template:

```
<ion-scroll zooming="true" direction="xy" style="width:90%">
   <div ng-if="loaded" bgeo lat="currentLat" lng="currentLong">
       <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 500px;"></div>
   </div>
</ion-scroll>
```

app.js run method:

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }

    if (window.cordova) {
      if (window.plugins && window.plugins.backgroundGeoLocation) {
        BackgroundGeolocation.configurePlugin(window.plugins.backgroundGeoLocation);
      }
    }
  });
})
```

The full source code is up on github at https://github.com/sahiltalwar88/binding-geolocation-issue. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Did you test your app on device or browser?

Comment: On the browser, it works perfectly. On the device, the button to load the page (almost always) does nothing; and when it does, most of the time the map is blank. It only worked properly the first time that I installed it on the device.
In order to cover my bases, I tried clearing the app's cache, uninstalling the app, toggling location services, and restarting the phone - all to no avail :(

Comment: Can you tell me your app requirement? It will be help to solve your issue.

Comment: It needs to: 
1. Get the user's location using normal geolocation (this primes background geolocation)
2. Display that location on the map on screen
3. Post the user's location to the server API, and update the map with it. 
(This is only a sample application that I built to demonstrate the issue; the production application is larger).

Comment: I think you need to when the user open the app , app get the user location . is it correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right - it should start EITHER when the user opens the app, OR when they go to the page in question. Either way is fine, though it's preferable for the app to start tracking the user's location as soon as they open the app.

BTW, I added my template and app.js to the original question, in case it's helpful. Thank you very much!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82254/discussion-between-cfprabhu-and-sahil-talwar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue was that I had to run bower install; I was missing several packages. Once I did that, I could use the ionic ready function and onDeviceReady just fine. Then, in order to get the iOS callback functions working, I had to update my syntax to work with ngCordova (which uses Q and promises) rather than callback functions, as the examples showed.

Here's the structure of my final code:

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
if(window.StatusBar) {
  StatusBar.styleDefault();
}

$location.path('/app');
$rootScope.$digest();

$rootScope.deviceReady = false; 

document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }

    var bgGeo = $cordovaBackgroundGeolocation;
    var deviceId = $cordovaDevice.getUUID();
    var addVisitUrl = 'your-url-goes-here';

    $rootScope.deviceId = deviceId;
    $rootScope.deviceReady = true;

    var posOptions = { timeout: 5000, enableHighAccuracy: true, maximumAge: 5000 };
    $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(posOptions)
        .then(function (location) {
            $rootScope.currentLat = location.coords.latitude;
            $rootScope.currentLong = location.coords.longitude;

            var yourAjaxCallback = function(response) {
                bgGeo.finish();
            };

            var callbackFn = function(location) {
                var data = {
                                deviceId: deviceId,
                                "location": {
                                    "latitude": location.latitude,
                                    "longitude": location.longitude
                                }
                            };
                $http.post(addVisitUrl, data);
                // Other code goes here

                yourAjaxCallback.call(this);
            };

            var failureFn = function(error) {
                alert('Background Geolocation Error: ' + error);
                // Other code goes here
            };

            bgGeo.configure({
                url: addVisitUrl,
                params: {
                    deviceId: deviceId,
                    "location": {
                        "latitude": $rootScope.currentLat,
                        "longitude": $rootScope.currentLong
                    }
                },
                desiredAccuracy: 10,
                stationaryRadius: 10,
                distanceFilter: 10,
                activityType: 'OtherNavigation',
                debug: true, 
                stopOnTerminate: false
            })
            .then(callbackFn, failureFn, callbackFn);

            bgGeo.start();
        });
    $rootScope.$digest();
    });
  });
})
```